# aws backup dynamodb to s3 but only today added records

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

is there any way to make daily dynamodb backup to s3 bucket but backup should contain only current day added records in dynamodb.

In other work, I want to take daily dynamodb backup to s3 but daily backup contain only today records added in dynamobd.

Please help if there is any way.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you enable [streams on your DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) table you get visibility into every item change in the table. You can write a [Lambda function that processes the stream events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb-example.html) and dumps items added to the table into an S3 bucket.